# Wait for animation to finish before calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
$.fn.blink = function(times, duration) {
    times = times || 2;

    while (times--) {
        this.fadeTo(duration, 0).fadeTo(duration, 1);
    }      
};
```

This makes blinking text. At last blink I want to execute a function so I changed it like this:

```
$.fn.blink = function(times, duration, callback) {
    times = times || 2;

    while (times--) {
        this.fadeTo(duration, 0).fadeTo(duration, 1);
    }

    if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
        callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
    }
};
```

The execution of callback is not at the right place. It seems to be fired when blinking starts. Any ideas how to call the function at last blinking?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cnm2f/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you a fiddle. The problem with your code was, that the loop iterated through your blinking stuff to fast, and the complete function was called immediately.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.blink').blink(5, 500, shout);
});

function shout() {
    alert('finished blinking');
}

$.fn.blinkOnce = function (duration, callback) {
    this.fadeTo(duration, 0).fadeTo(duration, 1, function () {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') callback.call(this);
    });
};

$.fn.blink = function (times, duration, callback) {
    var toBlink = this;
    var blinkComplete = function () {
        times--;
        if (times == 0) callback.call(this);
        else toBlink.blinkOnce(duration, blinkComplete);
    }

    toBlink.blinkOnce(duration, blinkComplete);
    return true;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgeLu/

Comment: I more thought of charlietfl solution but this works great with copy&paste :D!!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery animations have a `complete` callback argument since these methods are asynchronous

Try:

```
while (times--) {
        this.fadeTo(duration, 0).fadeTo(duration, 1, function(){
            /*last animation is complete*/
           if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
            } 

        });
    }
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/